# How can I use Ruby's Sanitize/Nokogiri to access untagged elements?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, sanitize

I'm trying to build a [Sanitize](http://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/#readme) transformer that accepts potentially malformed HTML input with elements outside of any tags at all, such as in this example:

```
out of a tag<p>in a tag</p>out again!
```

I want to have the transformer wrap any non-tagged elements in `<p>` tags so that the above transforms into:

```
<p>out of a tag</p><p>in a tag</p><p>out again!</p>
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to select the untagged element because it's not a node. I'm sure I'm missing something here. Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = 'out of a tag<p>in a tag</p>out again!'

Nokogiri::HTML(html).at_css('body').children.
  map {|x| '<p>' + x.text + '</p>' }.join('')
#=> "<p>out of a tag</p><p>in a tag</p><p>out again!</p>"
```

Text is stored in text nodes. Because CSS cannot select text nodes, you will have to use other methods to get them like `Nokogiri::XML::Node#children`.

Comment: @Aaron: If this has answered your question, could you click the check icon near the top of my answer? It will mark this question as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Adrian,

Your example works great in an irb session, but from the context of a transformer lambda, the lambda will only get called once, for the `<p>in a tag</p>` segment. :(

Turned out it was best to just dump the idea of doing this inside a Sanitize transformer, and it was simpler to just run Nokogiri on its own on the whole html document.

Points for you putting me on the right path, though! :)