# Why does this Nokogiri command strip out HTML tags?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is a continuation of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167809/how-can-i-use-rubys-sanitize-nokogiri-to-access-untagged-elements). I'm having problems with this Nokogiri snippet:

```
>> require 'nokogiri'
>> html = 'bad<p>markup</p>with<img src="foo.jpg">'
>> Nokogiri::HTML(html).at_css('body').children.map {|x| '<p>' + x.text + '</p>'}.join('') 
=> "<p>bad</p><p>markup</p><p>with</p><p></p>"
```

What happened to my image tag? It seems that Nokogiri might be stripping ALL the HTML tags present (including my original `<p>` around the word "markup"), and replacing them. How do I prevent this from happening? All I want to do is ensure that entirely untagged text is wrapped in a `<p>` tag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only wrap the element in a `p` tag if it is a text node, otherwise call `to_html` on it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = 'bad<p>markup</p>with<img src="foo.jpg">'

Nokogiri::HTML(html).at_css('body').
children.map do |x|
  if x.text?
    '<p>' + x.text + '</p>'
  else
    x.to_html
  end
end.join('') 
#=> "<p>bad</p>\n<p>markup</p><p>with</p><img src=\"foo.jpg\">"
```